# Xcode 5 Tests Not Running

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, testing, xcode5, xctest

I get the following message from Xcode when I try to run my tests:

```
2013-11-13 09:02:57.849 MyProject[378:303] Error loading /Users/tatami/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gcralijdlibafgeyfwfeiynnothy/Build/Products/Debug/MyProjectTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/MyProjectTests:  dlopen(/Users/tatami/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gcralijdlibafgeyfwfeiynnothy/Build/Products/Debug/MyProjectTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/MyProjectTests, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/tatami/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gcralijdlibafgeyfwfeiynnothy/Build/Products/Debug/MyProjectTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/MyProjectTests: open() failed with errno=1
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle '/Users/tatami/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gcralijdlibafgeyfwfeiynnothy/Build/Products/Debug/MyProjectTests.xctest'
```

This question has already been asked here: [Xcode 5 throws "Library not loaded" error when adding a test target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986277/xcode-5-throws-library-not-loaded-error-when-adding-a-test-target)
but the solution doesn't apply to me as this is a Mac app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have App Sandbox under Capabilities for your target enabled? Switching that off worked for me.

Comment: Well, what if you need Sandboxing? I don't want to disable Sandboxing every time I want to run my Unit Tests...

Comment: I also hit the same thing, and toggling off sandboxing helps. Too bad I of course need sandboxing in the app that I want to load into the tests...

Comment: Ah, here's instructions for testing a sandboxed app: http://marcschwieterman.com/blog/testing-in-the-sandbox/

Answer (score 4):

This is because of sandboxing.

Same issue also happens with OCUnit (in both Xcode 4 and 5): [XCTest - "Test failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378922/xctest-test-failed)

There's instructions for testing a sandboxed app here:
http://marcschwieterman.com/blog/testing-in-the-sandbox/

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. Why are not more people having this problem? The article you mention is from 2012 and the problem is still here..